# How to fix "com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Cannot find field" thrown from JsonFormat.parser().merge(...)?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I have 2 Protobuf models:

#### `User`:

```protobuf
package demo;

option java_package = "com.stackoverflow.question";
option java_outer_classname = "UserModel";

message User {

    message UserHeader {
        required int64 userId = 1;
    }

    required UserHeader header = 1;

    extensions 100 to 200;
}
```

#### `Employee`:

```protobuf
import "person.proto";

package demo;

option java_package = "com.stackoverflow.question";
option java_outer_classname = "EmployeeModel";

extend demo.User {
    optional EmployeeDetails details = 101;
}

message EmployeeDetails {
    required string department = 1;
    repeated Skill skills = 2;
}

message Skill {
    required int64 id = 1;
    required string name = 2;
}
```

I can create a model and serialize it to JSON using `JsonFormat.printer().print(...)`:

```java
ExtensionRegistry registry = ExtensionRegistry.newInstance();
EmployeeModel.registerAllExtensions(registry);

UserModel.User.Builder userBuilder = UserModel.User.newBuilder();
userBuilder.setHeader(UserModel.User.UserHeader.newBuilder().setUserId(1000));

EmployeeModel.EmployeeDetails.Builder employeeBuilder = EmployeeModel.EmployeeDetails.newBuilder();
employeeBuilder.setDepartment("Department 1")
               .addSkills(EmployeeModel.Skill.newBuilder()
                                             .setId(10_000)
                                             .setName("Skill 10_0000")
                                             .build())
               .addSkills(EmployeeModel.Skill.newBuilder()
                                             .setId(11_000)
                                             .setName("Skill 11_0000")
                                             .build());

userBuilder.setExtension(EmployeeModel.details, employeeBuilder.build());

final String json = JsonFormat.printer().print(userBuilder.build());
```

However deserializing the generated JSON back to Java objects fails with `com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Cannot find field: details in message demo.User`:

```js
UserModel.User.Builder userBuilder2 = UserModel.User.newBuilder();

JsonFormat.parser().merge(json, userBuilder2);
```

And there doesn't seem to be a way to pass an `ExtensionRegistry` to `JsonFormat.parser()` either.

Is there a way to make this *Protobuf → JSON → Protobuf* serialization/deserialization chain work?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `JsonFormat`'s parser [does not support extensions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/YtQV7eSj_7I/overview).